# Touchpad only works when booting from USB

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad, 20.04, 19.10

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Lenovo P52. When I booted from USB the touchpad worked fine but now that its installed it doesn't. The trackpad works in windows 10 (laptop is dual booted).

I've tried installing 19.10 and the same thing happened. I've taken the following steps to fix the issue but none have worked.

1. Ensure trackpad is enabled in mouse settings
2. Ensure trackpad is detected when `xinput` is run

   Output:

   ```
   Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Anywhere 2                    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Master 2S                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎜   ↳ Elan TrackPoint                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ AT Raw Set 2 keyboard                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Logitech MX Anywhere 2                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
       ↳ Logitech MX Master 2S                     id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ```
3. Add `psmouse.elantech_smbus=0` to kernel parameters
4. Add `i8042.reset` to kernel parameters
5. Ensure trackpad is enabled in the BIOS

Any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: Boot the USB again (:Try Ubuntu"). Figure out why the touchpad works. `sudo journalctl -b 0` will show logs since startup, which includes touchpad/trackpad logs.

Comment: Hi waltinator! I've run the command and now I have a pretty long log file. Whats the best way to put it here?
As an aside, I rebooted my laptop this morning (which I've done multiple times since installing 20.04lts) and the touchpad suddenly works. I'm not sure if this is a one-off but or not though.

Comment: Do not post the whole log file! 99+% of the log entries are not of interest. Use an editor (on  a copy of the file), and keep ONLY the "touchpad" entries, plus 2 lines before and 2 lines after. You should end up with a max of 50 lines, and probably fewer than 50. Edit your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools. Comments are for US to ask YOU to improve your Question, to help us help you.